# Why DocumentData uncompress corrupts SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0

Tags: metadata

I use `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 FORCE_SOURCE_DATE=1 xelatex test`
to create reproducible PDF files.

Since I want to understand some detail I wrote `test.tex` with uncompression.

```
%\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\special{dvipdfmx:config z 0}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Of course, I do not like `xelatex` specific command `\special{dvipdfmx:config z 0}` to refrain from compression.
All works fine, a diff shows, results are the same when compiling twice.

If I replace the `\special` command by the more general `\DocumentMetadata`,
then a diff unveils

```
$ diff -a test.pdf testX.pdf
220c220
<      <rdf:li>2023-12-06T21:36:39Z</rdf:li>
---
>      <rdf:li>2023-12-06T21:36:32Z</rdf:li>
226,228c226,228
<    <xmp:CreateDate>2023-12-06T21:36:39Z</xmp:CreateDate>
<    <xmp:ModifyDate>2023-12-06T21:36:39Z</xmp:ModifyDate>
<    <xmp:MetadataDate>2023-12-06T21:36:39Z</xmp:MetadataDate>
---
>    <xmp:CreateDate>2023-12-06T21:36:32Z</xmp:CreateDate>
>    <xmp:ModifyDate>2023-12-06T21:36:32Z</xmp:ModifyDate>
>    <xmp:MetadataDate>2023-12-06T21:36:32Z</xmp:MetadataDate>
230c230
<    <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:70381c59-1666-4bc2-80a7-7e613d06022e</xmpMM:InstanceID>
---
>    <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:2c37e4bc-7448-455d-8793-19c3e55d01ca</xmpMM:InstanceID>
256c256
< <</Creator(LaTeX)/Producer(xetex-0.999995)/CreationDate(D:20231206213639Z)/ModDate(D:20231206213639Z)>>
---
> <</Creator(LaTeX)/Producer(xetex-0.999995)/CreationDate(D:20231206213632Z)/ModDate(D:20231206213632Z)>>
```

exposing the correct `CreationDate` includint eh time also
and there are more timestamps probably introduced by `\DocumentMetadata`.

Comparing one version with `\special` and one with `\DocumentMetadata` is also instructive.
It is a bit long but the `\special` version shows:

```
< <</Creator( XeTeX output 1970.01.01:0000)/Producer(xdvipdfmx \(20220710\))/CreationDate(D:19700101000000-00'00')>>
```

and `CreationDate(D:19700101000000-00'00')` corresponds with `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0`, correct.

By the way, replacing `\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}` by `\DocumentMetadata{pdfversion=1.8}` corrupts reproducibility also.

Also interesting: This behavior is not specific to `xelatex`,
also `lualatex` and `pdflatex` behave essentially like that.

Comment: it should work with a current pdfmanagement, the epoch handling has been corrected end of august https://github.com/latex3/pdfresources/issues/53

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you do the work and I get the points, sounds like a fair division of labour

Comment: so my thanks go explicitly to Ulrike kkk. 
But I think I must wait until the bugfix arrived in my texlife distribution...

Comment: which texlive do you have? With texlive 2023 you only need to update, and in other texlive you will never get it.

Answer (score 0):

If I use

```
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\special{dvipdfmx:config z 0}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

with an up to date texlive I get no diff and the xml dates show the start of the epoch not, as your diff shows the current time

```
   <xmp:CreateDate>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</xmp:CreateDate>
   <xmp:ModifyDate>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</xmp:ModifyDate>
   <xmp:MetadataDate>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</xmp:MetadataDate>
```